# I have 16,000 URLs, I need to get the facebook graph ID of each one

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-file, facebook-fql

I have 16,000 URLs. each is a Facebook open graph object. I need to get the open graph data for each of the 16k URLs.

The way I'm thinking about doing this is first finding the open graph object ID of each URL, and then in a nightly cron job, I would do a graph.facebook.com batch request for the details of each object.

However the first step I am unsure of how to do.  How do I get all the Object IDs of 16,000 URLs? (all at once). perhaps FQL?

please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$batched_request='[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"method/fql.query?query=select id, url from object_url where url in ('.$urls.')"}]';

$urls should be around 300 urls. and then repeat

Comment: This fwl.query method is deprecated since 2.1, you have to use the graph api now

Answer (score 2):

If your URL looks like this:

**http://www.facebook.com/WHATEVER**

just do this:

**https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=WHATEVER**

... the object ID as well as a bunch of other info will be returned as the result. You can also request multiple objects as in:

**https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=WHATEVER1,WHATEVER2,WHATEVER3**

(test this out here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: i realize this can be done by simply appending the URL to graph.facebook.com however I need this done with 16k links. thus this method won't work. any other thoughts? perhaps using FQL?

Comment: why do you beleive it will not work for 16000 links? if you have the list in a text file you just to do a quick text find and replace

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=WHATEVER1,WHATEVER2,WHATEVER3 works and should be the preferred solution, since FQL is now officially deprecated: "Version 2.0 of the Facebook Platform API is the last version where FQL will be available. Versions after 2.0 will not support FQL. Please migrate your applications to use Graph API instead of FQL. Please see our changelog for current version information." (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql)

Answer (score -1):

i dont think it be possible to get 16K url's information in a one action

you can set cron job for this & try to get information about 10 url every time

Comment: the question said he will be using a cron job, not all 16k at once.

Comment: "so he can try url"? What does that mean?

Comment: Rees said 
_i realize this can be done by simply appending the URL to graph.facebook.com however I need this done with 16k links. thus this method won't work. any other thoughts? perhaps using FQL?_ 
& i answered 
_i dont think it be possible to get 16K url's information in a one action_ 
This means you cant get information  about 16k url via fql in one action so you need to try it with cronjob & if you want to use cronjob you can use Get from link (or url like this :https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=WHATEVER)