# Getting Open Graph object ID from page URL

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-opengraph

how can I get the Facebook Object ID paired to a page from the page itself?

For example, I asked directly for the Object ID 325186347604922 and i got:

```
<pre>
{
  "url": ".../ricetta-bigne_salati.htm", 
  "type": "ricettepercucinare:recipe", 
  "title": "Bignè salati", 
  "image": [
    {
      "url": ".../magazine/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/101-150x150.jpg", 
      "width": 150, 
      "height": 150
    }
  ], 
  "description": "Gli ingredienti e la procedura per preparare la ricetta Bignè salati.", 
  "data": {
    "course": "Antipasto", 
    "foreign_id": 130400
  }, 
  "updated_time": "2013-03-28T10:12:17+0000", 
  "id": "325186347604922", 
  "application": {
    "id": "118665634826424", 
    "name": "Ricettepercucinare.com", 
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=118665634826424"
  }
}</pre>
```

But how, for example, this page http://www.ricettepercucinare.com/ricetta-bigne_salati.htm could know its own ID?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the ID? Can't you use the URL pretty much interchangeably?

Comment: I need it because i would like to verify, when an user is in the specific page, if that object is envolved in such previous activity (to be compliant with Open Graph terms, read it as "Story") done by the user with it.

Comment: Same question, can't you use the ID for that too?

Comment: I do not manage Facebook Object ID on a website, but URLs. What I need to know is the object ID providing the URL. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not currently possible to look up an object ID from the URL - although it should be.

It should be possible using:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.ricettepercucinare.com/ricetta-bigne_salati.htm
```

but this isn't working.

Please raise a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

What about this guy's solution: http://blog.odbol.com/?p=9

```
function facebookGetIdForUrl(url, callback) {
  //see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/
  FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: "SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = '" + url + "'"
  }, function(response) {
    callback(response[0].id);
  });
}

facebookGetIdForUrl("http://facebook.com", function (id) {
  alert("Facebook ID = " + id);
});
```

Comment: Adding code sample or more explanations would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with FQL:

```
select id, url from object_url where url in ('http://www.watchth.is/movies/9166-baraka')
```

[See it in the Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20id,%20url%20from%20object_url%20where%20url%20in%20%28%27http://www.watchth.is/movies/9166-baraka%27%29), or simply use this ajax call: `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20id%2C%20url%20from%20object_url%20where%20url%20in%20('http%3A%2F%2Fwww.watchth.is%2Fmovies%2F9166-baraka')&format=json&suppress_http_code=1`

[Thanks to Rees' response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474037/i-have-16-000-urls-i-need-to-get-the-facebook-graph-id-of-each-one)